# Edges showing through

Tags: modeling

i have followed a tutorial and made this human base model but the thing is that the eyes i have modelled and positioned apparently looked fine, when I zoom in the edges appear to be alright, but when I zoom out, the edges appear as if the object is projecting out of another object(i.e the face)[image]. can someone please let me know what is the problem here or is it alright if this happens?
[image]

[image]

Comment: What you're seeing is called Z-fighting.  As the camera gets further from the mesh, it loses depth precision and becomes uncertain about whether the eye or the lid is closer.  Solution?  Thicken the eyelid.  This isn't just for modelling purposes-- real life eyelids are thicker than beginning artists realize.

Comment: So when if i zoom out and render the image as it is now it will still show the eyeballs like that?

Comment: I have thickened the eyelids but it is still showing the eyeball when zoomed out

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you're seeing is just caused by the Display Wire setting being turned on. An actual render will use higher precision depth calculations and the eye shouldn't appear through the mesh. Just do a quick, low sample render?

Comment: yeah it did well in render. Thanks